# Weird case where map function is not called with a BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, angular, functional-programming, rxjs

I'm front of a weid case in my Angular App about a map's RxJS not called.

Please, take a look to this sample of code :

```
const userSource = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined);
const user = userSource.asObservable();

user.map(user => {
  const shouldPass = !!user;
  console.log('shouldPass', shouldPass, user);
  if (user === null) {
    console.log('go to login');
    // this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
  return shouldPass;
});
Rx.Observable
  .throwError(new Error('HTTP 401'))
  .subscribe(
    user => userSource.next(user),
    e => userSource.next(null)
  );
```

This code (that I translate into plain JavaScript) is placed in a function dedicated to load User entity from server (here replaced by a throw Error to simulate an HTTP error) and then `emit` on a `BehaviorSubject`.
In this exemple, the `user.map` is called only one time during the initialization of the `BehaviorSubject`.

For me, it should be called twice time, right ? One time for the initialization and another time when an error is thrown from the observable.

Answer (score 1):

Observables are lazy (most of the time), they don't execute the code you declared until you subscribe. Subscription takes three arguments (`next`, `error`, `complete`) - functions that may or may not execute, depending on what is passed through observable chain.

In your example only `error` callback is executed, this:

```
Rx.Observable
  .empty()
  .subscribe(...)
```

would only execute `complete` callback (you didn't specified it).

```
Rx.Observable
  .of(123)
  .subscribe(...)
```

would execute both `next` and `complete` callbacks.

Basic rules are:

- `next` callback is called if there is no error
- `error` is called then there is no error
- `complete` is called when observable completes and there is no error

For more info see:

- http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observer
- http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subscription
- http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#observables-as-generalizations-of-functions

Answer (score 0):

The question is where do you subscribe? To `user`? Because that's the same as subscribing to `userSource.asObservable()`.

I guess you want to subscribe to the result of `user.map()` so you need to assign it to a variable:

```
const userSource = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined);
const user = userSource.asObservable();

const bla = user.map(user => {
  const shouldPass = !!user;
  // console.log('shouldPass', shouldPass, user);
  if (user === null) {
    // console.log('go to login');
    // this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
  return shouldPass;
});

bla.subscribe(console.log);

Rx.Observable
  .throw(new Error('HTTP 401'))
  .subscribe(
    user => userSource.next(user),
    e => userSource.next(null)
  );
```

Also note that you need to subscribe to `bla` before `Rx.Observable.throw()` because otherwise you do emit into `userSource.next(user)` but nobody is listening (there's no observer).

With the above code you'll see `false` printed twice.